# Why does this Javascript DOM code only working FF, but not IE?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
//create an instance of the XML parser
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{ 
    //Checking if the browser is IE
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async="false"; //make sure doc is fully loaded
    xmlDoc.load(strPath) //load the file in the parser
    if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) 
    {
        alert("Error #: " + xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode;        
    }        
}

//for mozilla based browsers
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)       
{
    xmlDoc= document.implementation.createDocument("","doc",null); 
    xmlDoc.async=false; //make sure doc is fully loaded
    loaded = xmlDoc.load(strPath);
    if(!loaded)
    {
       alert("Error in XML File");
    }            
}

//Parse the XML
var root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
level1Nodes = root.children;
for(var index1 = 0; index1 < level1Nodes.length; index1++)
{
    //Extract the markup content from XML
    var level1Node = level1Nodes[index1];
    var strName = level1Node.children[0].textContent;
    var strHeader1 = level1Node.children[1].tagName;
    var strHeader1Content = level1Node.children[1].textContent;
}
```

Is the "children" property available in the IE DOM Parser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IE, an XML document does not implement the same document object model as an HTML document; in particular, XML `Node` objects don't have the `children` property, which is non-standard.

You should use the `childNodes` collection instead. However be aware that in Firefox and other browsers - and, IIRC, under very specific circumstances in IE - this collection will also include text nodes that contain only whitespace, such as line breaks in the original XML file. So you will need to check the `nodeType` property: if it has the value 1, it is an Element, and will have properties such as `tagName`.

Furthermore, as MSXML implements [DOM Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/), whereas Firefox implements [DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/), you won't be able to use the `textContent` property, which was introduced in Level 3. Instead, you will have to iterate over the `childNodes` of `nodeType` === 3 and concatenate their `nodeValue` properties, and probably then will want to trim any leading or trailing whitespace. Alternatively, if you know that there will only ever be textNodes in there, call the `normalize` method of the element first to make sure it only has one text node child.

Nobody ever said this stuff was supposed to be easy :-(

Answer (score 1):

`children` is an object in IE6. Perhaps there's an inconsistency in that IE's first child is a text node, whereas in other browsers the first child is a DOM element node? Usually you'd use `.childNodes` and `.childNodes.length` and check for `.nodeType==1` in a loop to run through the children.