# documentElement has no children

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, cross-browser

```js
var element = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<foo><bar></bar></foo>', 'application/xml').documentElement;
var children = element.children;
document.write('' + element);
document.write('' + children);
```

In Chrome and Firefox I see "[object Element][object HTMLCollection]".

But in IE 9-11, I see "[object Element]undefined".

Why does `documentElement` have no children?

What is the best way in IE 9+ (and Chrome and FF) of getting all child elements of an element?

Comment: Use `childNodes` if `children` is `undefined`. Actually I think you'll get the same problem in Safari.

Comment: @raina77ow, but I want child *elements*, not child *nodes*.

Comment: I see, but it's IE, you know. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464328/why-does-this-javascript-dom-code-only-workin-ff-but-not-ie).

Comment: @raina77ow, hm, good link. It surprises me that `documentElement` would not implement the `Element` interface, but ah well.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach I can recommend is to use `Array.prototype.filter()` on the element's child nodes:

```
function getChildElements(element) {
     return Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes)
     .filter(function (e) { return e.nodeType === 1; });
}

var childElements = getChildElements(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`children`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-children) is defined in [`ParentNode`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#parentnode) interface, which is implemented by [`Element`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#element).

However, it seems that on IE, `ParentNode` is implemented by `HTMLElement` instead of `Element`.

Interestingly, this dirty approach works for single instances on IE:

```js
element.__proto__ = HTMLElement.prototype;
var children = element.children;          // Now this works
element.__proto__ = Element.prototype;    // Restore [[Prototype]]
```

In order to fix IE's problem for all `Element` instances, you can use

```js
var obj = Element.prototype,
    prop = 'children',
    desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, prop);
if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && desc)
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, desc);
```